# How do I set up Cloudflare's Quad-1 with DNS Encryption?

Tags: networking, encryption, dns

I read a lot recently about [`1.1.1.1`](https://1.1.1.1/), or Cloudflare's DNS provider.

They supposedly have a system to allow DNS-over-TLS or other such secure ways of using DNS, however I see no option in my DNS settings enable encryption.

Is encryption automatically enabled when I use `1.1.1.1`? Do I need to enable a hidden option or install a package? What steps do I need to make sure I'm safe?

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple ways that I know of. Maybe others will know of additional methods. If there is an approach that uses Ubuntu's default capabilities, I'd love someone to speak up and point the way!

1) Use a DNS privacy stub resolver such as Stubby (https://github.com/getdnsapi/stubby). This runs as a daemon either on your computer (listening on 127.0.0.1) or perhaps on a server of your choosing. You tell Stubby what DNS servers to use (in this case, 1.1.1.1) and whether or not to use TLS when talking to those servers, etc. Then you simply tell Ubuntu to use the address Stubby is at for DNS (if running it locally, then you'd change your DNS servers in network manager to 127.0.0.1). Stubby then handles all your DNS and gets the information from the external servers securely.

2) This method is more limited to browsing. But Firefox 62 is said to include settings for routing all browser-related DNS requests through DNS-over-HTTPS (which 1.1.1.1 handles). This will not route non-browser DNS through HTTPS, though, and is therefore not the all-around solution.